# Create a World Cup overview

Tags: code-golf

I'm not to sure about the title so feel free to suggest a better one.

### Task/challenge

Create an overview for the World Cup tracking the cup from the group phase till the finals.

### Group phase

There are 8 groups (Group A, B, C, .., H) which can be found [>> here <<](http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/groups/)
Each group has 4 teams/countries.
There will be 6 matches per group.
**Scoring** (for matches)
- Winning gives you 3 points
- Draw gives both teams 1 point
- Loss gives no points.

After those 6 matches the 2 teams with the highest score will go on to the second stage.
If there are 2 or more teams with the same score the decision will be made based on the match between those teams.
Lets say the Netherlands and Chile have equal points, then whoever won that match will go on to the second stage.
It can happen there is still a draw, in that case a decision will be made based on goal difference.
The goal difference is calculated by Goals_Scored - Goals_Conceded. (both goals during group phase) 
There is a possibility that even this will keep a draw. In this case you will have to select the team manually in your program (or use the bonus {1})

### Second Stage

During this round you can no longer gain points. You either win or lose.
If there is a draw after the regular playtime (90 minutes) there will be overtime. Overtime is 2x 15 minutes.
If there is no winner after that they will take penalties. 
Each team takes 5 shots and the team with most goals wins.
If there is no winner after those 5 shots the teams will keep shooting until 1 team scores and the other doesn't.
For the penalties you can either manually select the winner or use the bonus.

All matches will stay like this from now on.

## Useful information

After the group phase the matches will be as follows:

### Round of 16

Number 1 Group A Vs. Number 2 Group B {Match 49}
Number 1 Group C Vs. Number 2 Group D {Match 50}
Number 1 Group E Vs. Number 2 Group F {Match 51}
Number 1 Group G Vs. Number 2 Group H {Match 52}
Number 1 Group B Vs. Number 2 Group A {Match 53}
Number 1 Group D Vs. Number 2 Group C {Match 54}
Number 1 Group F Vs. Number 2 Group E {Match 55}
Number 1 Group H Vs. Number 2 Group G {Match 56}

### Quarter finals

Winner Match 49 Vs. Winner Match 50 {Match 57}
Winner Match 51 Vs. Winner Match 52 {Match 58}
Winner Match 53 Vs. Winner Match 54 {Match 59}
Winner Match 55 Vs. Winner Match 56 {Match 60}

### Semi finals

Winner Match 57 Vs. Winner Match 58 {Match 61}
Winner Match 59 Vs. Winner Match 60 {Match 62}

### 3rd/4th place

Loser Match 61 Vs. Loser Match 62 {Match 63}

### Finals

Winner Match 61 Vs. Winner Match 62 {Match 64}

## Functionality

Your program should be able to do the following:
- Display the groups.
- Accept scores for group phase.
- Fill in the entire schedule for the second stage.
- Accept manually selecting a winner (if you're not using the bonus)

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so your score is based on the length of your code and the lowest score wins.

## Bonus

The first bonus requires some explaining.
Its about the score difference bit. If there is no winner after that FIFA will look at the world ranking.
You will earn a bonus of `-20 points` if you use the world ranking to determine the winner.

The second bonus will get you `-60 points`, to gain this bonus you will need to be able to display how the team won in the second stage.
Either a normal win, Won by scoring in overtime (also show how many times was scored in overtime for both teams) or won by shooting penalties (show penalties scored for both teams)

This was quite a bit to write so I might got carried away and forgot to explain or tell a few things.
Feel free to ask and suggest things I might have forgotten or aren't clear yet.

## Restrictions

- You can't use external resources. So you're not allowed to download all the info from the internet or anything similar.
  The one exception is that you are allowed to use the internet for looking up the world ranking if you're going after the bonus.

Remember the world cup is not a one day event. So try to make it user friendly.
Having the user type in all team names and all scores each time they run your program is not user friendly.
The assumption that the use will keep your program open at all times is false, say hello to windows auto update and black outs. :)

Have fun and happy coding.

Comment: Why subtract the country names from the code? Including it would add an interesting kolmogorov-complexity component to the challenge, I think. Also I don't think fetching and evaluating the web request for the first bonus is remotely possible in 20 characters.

Comment: @m.buettner Agreed to the bonus, any suggestion how many points it should award? And im not familiar with the kolmogorov-complexity, I will look it up and edit the challenge accordingly.

Comment: With kolmogorov-complexity, I was just implying that it would be an interesting part of the challenge to compress the country names and setting up the groups.

Comment: @m.buettner I will remove the bit of subtracting the names, should I also add the Kolmogorov tag to this challenge then?

Comment: I'd like to solve this challenge in C#/WinForms. Do I have to include the generated code for the GUI into my score?

Comment: I suppose you mean the styling of your forms right? In that case no you don't have to include that.

Comment: Maybe this should be updated for the Rugby World Cup which is just starting now...